# Emitter Particle System not using Density Vertex Group(Single Vertex Emitter)

Tags: particles

Blender ignores a "Single Vertex" vertex group ,  when assigned as emitter in the density panel of the particle system. It simply emits from the all the verts.
No other modifiers are applied to the emitting plane.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you've set *Emission > Source > Faces*, and as you've painted the central vertex it considers that all the faces that this vertex is part of will be affected. So you need to subdivide your plane a bit so that only the central face will be affected.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Oh,completely missed the Emit From " setting. No need to subdivide it further ,simply switching from "Faces to Verts" does the trick.